# Group Policy Setting to allow creation of child process

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have a SharePoint 2013 solution which calls the SelectPDF DLL to convert html into a PDF. It works fine in our Dev environment but not in any of the higher environments. The error I get is:

> "Conversion failure error 1260"

I've read [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-from-HTML-to-PDF-09ce2a1d/view/Discussions/4) that this is caused by a Group Policy setting, which makes sense since we have group policy applied in all environments except DEV, including AppLocker settings. When I disable the group policy SelectPDF works, but when I enable it the PDF generation process errors.

I've read that SelectPDF needs to have permission to create a child process, but I don't know how to do this, and I haven't had any luck searching for an answer. Can anyone suggest what Group Policy setting would grant the account running the SelectPDF conversion this permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If AppLocker is causing the issue you should be able to see an error in the logs (under event viewer under Application and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows, double-click AppLocker. )

If AppLocker is causing the issue need to add the executable being blocked as an exception to whichever rule is set to deny.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below setting in Group Policy
Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Replace a process level token

> This security setting determines which user accounts can call the CreateProcessAsUser() application programming interface (API) so that one service can start another. An example of a process that uses this user right is Task Scheduler. For information about Task Scheduler, see Task Scheduler overview.
>
> Default: Network Service, Local Service.

One approach that I suggest is to figure a way to configure selectPDF to run as a Local Service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it just changing the GPO settings as you suggested but it still errors. You mentioned needing to run it as a local service. Why would this be any different to running it from within SharePoint with the credentials of one of the SharePoint accounts?

Comment: @GregtheIncredulous I suggested to run a local service because that service is granted the permission by default. If you have already tried adding the SharePoint account to this GPO setting, that is also fine.